# Android how to get sent/received email information

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am just curious about.
From Message Inbox/Outbox. we can retrieve :phone number,message body,date,locked status,StatusOnSim etc.
So Can we retrieve from email (sent+inbox):Email_id,Subject,Body,CC,BCC etc.
I want to retrive all this thing from my email like Email_id,Subject,Body,CC,BCC etc

if any one have idea regarding this than please help me on it.

Comment: Have You checked com.android.emailcommon.provider.Mailbox and other classes from this package? Probably (with bit of hacking and hardcode) it might be possible even from usual application.

Answer (score 1):

Code to send email information:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
     "ur mail id" });
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ur subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ur text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(FileName));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose"));
```

it cant retrieve data like Email_id,Subject,Body,CC,BCC etc from ur mail box. But it possible in Message inbox.

Comment: Thank you Vishnu User not send email from my code(app).User send a email from Android Gmail service.I want to receive this from my apps.I think I understand my issue.This code only works within our App its not access data from Android Gmail service app's data. @Vishnu